# Creating multiple progress bar programmatically inside a grid

Tags: wpf, grid, progress-bar

I would like to create multiple progress bars inside a grid or table through code (VB.Net). The layout of the structure is as follow:

```
Game 1      [ Progress Bar 1 ]
            Downloading 2MB of 4MB

Game 2      [ Progress Bar 2 ]
            Downloading 4MB of 5MB

Game 3      [ Progress Bar 3 ]
            Download completed
```

Will need to be able to update the values of selected progress bar in real time.
Should I create a new class and inside this class add an array of progress bar?

---

Edit:

Say I incorporate the answer suggested to use ItemsControl to display my group of progress bars inside a show_progress_page (UI). I have another download_page that is actually using WebClient DownloadFileAsync to download all the games.

How should I put the functionalities inside download_page to be able to create progress bar inside show_progress_page?

I've tried creating this class download_page but after it loads the UI does not show this new progress bar

```
Public Class download_page 
Public CollectionDownloads As New ObservableCollection(Of [DownloadAppViewModel])()

Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    Dim individualDownload As New DownloadAppViewModel()
    individualDownload.GameName = "hello"
    individualDownload.TotalSize = 20
    individualDownload.DownloadedSize = 5
    CollectionDownloads.Add(individualDownload)
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: [Are your bindings correct](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very easy using the [MVVM pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) ;)

Create a class to represent each transfer:

```
public class GameDownloadViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _gameName;
    public string GameName
    {
        get { return _gameName; }
        set
        {
            _gameName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("GameName");
        }
    }

    public string StatusText
    {
        get
        {
            if (_downloadedSize < _totalSize)
                return string.Format("Downloading {0} MB of {1} MB", _downloadedSize, _totalSize);
            return "Download completed";
        }
    }

    private long _totalSize;
    public long TotalSize
    {
        get { return _totalSize; }
        set
        {
            _totalSize = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TotalSize");
            OnPropertyChanged("Progress");
            OnPropertyChanged("StatusText");
        }
    }

    private long _downloadedSize;
    public long DownloadedSize
    {
        get { return _downloadedSize; }
        set
        {
            _downloadedSize = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("DownloadedSize");
            OnPropertyChanged("Progress");
            OnPropertyChanged("StatusText");
        }
    }

    public double Progress
    {
        get
        {
            if (_totalSize != 0)
                return 100.0 * _downloadedSize / _totalSize;
            return 0.0;
        }
    }
}
```

Bind an `ItemsControl` to an `ObservableCollection<GameDownloadViewModel>`, and define the template to be used to display each item:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding GameDownloads}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                           Text="{Binding GameName}" >
                <ProgressBar Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                             Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="{Binding Progress}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                           Text="{Binding StatusText}" >
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

When the progress changes, just update the properties of the relevant `GameDownloadViewModel`, and the view will be updated accordingly.

Comment: sorry, do you have example in VB.net on how to inherit from ViewModelBase? I'm using a code converter but it returns error on Inherits ViewModelBase and on OnPropertyChanged:                Public Class GameDownloadViewModel
        Inherits ViewModelBase
        Private _gameName As String
        Public Property GameName() As String
            Get
                Return _gameName
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _gameName = value
                OnPropertyChanged("GameName")
            End Set
        End Property

Comment: Do i have to download ViewModelBase as a separate class? Sorry I'm stuck here and feels very frustrated as I tried to convert my entire project back to C# and hit a lot of error

Comment: @simeh, this class is the one presented in the article about MVVM (see the link at the beginning of my answer)

Comment: @Thomas, is it possible to provide some code sample for ObservableCollection<GameDownloadViewModel>?

Comment: @simeh, what do you mean? Just declare a property of this type: `public ObservableCollection<GameDownloadViewModel> Downloads { get; private set; }`

Comment: @Thomas, say I have a button to add this transfer, I should create an array of GameDownloadViewModel? Possible to include code on how to create this object (transfer 1, transfer 2, etc) and assign values to it?

Comment: Ok, ObservableCollection should be in a new calling class together with with its method to initialize the above XAML and set the progressbar value? Example: Public class Window1 {  ObservableCollection<GameDownloadViewModel> Downloads { get; private set; } public Window1 {   InitializeComponent(); DataContext = this;  Downloads.add (new GameDownloadViewModel { GameName="Game 1"}); }

Comment: @simeh, typically in MVVM you don't do this in the code-behind, you create a ViewModel class and you assign an instance of this class to the DataContext of the view. Just read the article I linked to, it explains everything

Comment: @Thomas, I'm using ObservableCollection now. However after I add an item to it, the UI does not reflect this changes. Able to advise based on the edited code segment above?

Comment: @Thomas, I have my project outsource to freelancer and PeoplePerHour http://www.freelancer.com/projects/Visual-Basic-NET/WPF-Visual-Basic-small-function.html   Would you be interested to bid? Its largely based on your code above

Comment: ok thanks for replying Thomas. I'm  just wondering if according to MVVM pattern, shouldn't each individual download be placed into a Model (eg: SingleDownload.cs class file) and collection of individual download be placed into a ViewModel (eg: CollectionOfDownload.cs)? Your c# code above seems like combining this two into one part?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean... In my code the GameDownloadViewModel represents a single download. The model can be whatever you want.

Comment: I've created 2 instance of DownloadAppViewModel but it seems that instance 1 is overwriting instance 2's progress bar value based on the code above. If I try to set public double Progress {...} to private, I can stop the overwriting but the progress bar doesn't show progress

Comment: @simeh, the comments are not the right place to discuss a complex problem, there is no room to post code... you should post a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Do not create an array of progress-bars, create a bindable class that models the data your need to display then bind a collection of said class to an `ItemsControl` which has a template with the form of one of those grid rows:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Data}"
              Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <!-- Synchronize size accross rows,
                         works in conjunction with Grid.IsSharedSizeScope. -->
                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A" />
                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="B" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding GameName}" />
                <ProgressBar Grid.Column="1" Minimum="0" Maximum="1" Value="{Binding DownloadProgress}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding DownloadProgressString}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Then you just need to update the properties of the download object and the UI will reflect the changes.

Comment: We came up with almost the same XAML code... but you were faster, so +1 ;). I'll leave my answer anyway because it also shows the ViewModel part.

Comment: @HB, hi, will you be able to advice on the edited question on trying to make the entire code above show at UI? I've created new object of DownloadAppViewModel and assigns value to it but it is not showing at UI. Thanks

Comment: @HB, I have my project outsource to freelancer and PeoplePerHour http://www.freelancer.com/projects/Visual-Basic-NET/WPF-Visual-Basic-small-function.html   Would you be interested to bid? Its largely based on your code above